# How to use root anaconda environment in Pycharm

Tags: anaconda, pycharm

I am new to anaconda and pycharm. I wanted to ask that why can I use all root anaconda packages when I use spyder, but when I use pycharm I have to create a new environment and install all the packages again, which also take up alot of memory space. Can I not use the root env of anaconda in pycharm?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [link](https://medium.com/infinity-aka-aseem/how-to-setup-pycharm-with-an-anaconda-virtual-environment-already-created-fb927bacbe61) that shows how to set the anaconda interpreter for pycharm. I recommand you to use environments because all the packages have dependencies that are difficult to reproduce and you can export and import your environment with yml files.

Comment: I made an env rn and added libraries like Pandas, numpy, scikt-learn and the env folder is like 1.2 gb. That is alot. Anyway i can reduce that?

Comment: I am not sure but you can try mini-conda. I think when you create an enviornment  all root libs are imported.

Comment: @Moon did my answer help you? If it helped, accept my answer, please.